# Maximum and continous derivatives $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have a problem to prove that this function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}~~~~~~x\in R$$

takes every value in its domain and has continuous derivatives of all orders. Then I have to prove that it has local maximum at $x=0$

*My steps*
We need to prove that the function is analytic. Otherwise, that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ since the power series is convergent and continuous in its radius of convergence - it takes each value in its domain.
$$ e^x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{(\frac{x^2}{n})^n}{n!} $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_jx^j \\ b_j=\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}~~~~~\text{if    } j=x^{2^n}\\0~~\text{otherwise}$$

From Cauchy-Hadamard:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{a_n} =\frac{1}{R}\\\lim_{j\to\infty} \sup \sqrt[j]{b_j} = \sqrt[j]{\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}}\to 0$$

Thus $\frac{1}{R}= 0 \Rightarrow R=\infty$

The derivative is convergent on given intervals $[-a, a]$:
$$j\cdot\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}\cdot x^{j-1}\leq j\cdot\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}\cdot a^j$$

Now we have a value at each point and $C^\infty$ class. For maximum at zero:

$$f'(x)=j\cdot\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}\cdot x^{j-1}=0~~~\text{if  }x=0\\ f''(x) = j\cdot (j-1)\cdot\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}\cdot x^{j-2}= j^2-\cdot\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}\cdot x^{j-2}$$

For $0$ to be maximum, the second derivative should be negative, however, if $j\to 0$ the term:
$$\frac{\log_2(\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2(j)}}{\log_2(j)\cdot \log_2(j)!}$$
tends to zero, thus there stays always positive $j^2$. **That's not good for the sake of the proof**. Please, help.

Additionally, I may have noticed that I would have to use $- log(j)\cdot{log(j)}$ in nominator since $(\frac{-1}{n})^n=\log_2(-\frac{1}{j})^{\log_2{j}}$, but it still tends to zero from the left side

Comment: Hint: show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}(e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}-1)$ converges normally (absolutely uniformly on any compact set, since $e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}-1=O(|x|^2/n)$ for $n$ much larger than the maximum of $|x|$ in the given compact set); if you are allowed to use complex analysis, this implies that $f(x)+\log 2$ is entire and you can differentiate term by term as many times as you want; with real analysis, you need induction to show that the series of derivatives of various orders converge again normally; for the second part a simple computation shows that $f'(0)=0, f''(0) <0$ etc

Comment: How to do it without complex analysis?